# What are the ways a default export can be given an implicit name?

Tags: javascript, editor, es6-modules

Default exports don't have an enforced name but an unnamed default export,

```js
export default 'foo';
```

can be named implicitly like so:

```js
const Foo = 'foo';
export default Foo;
```

Named functions are also implicitly named by nature:

```js
export default function namedFunction() { ... }
```

This implicit naming is picked up by editors to help with autocompletion and automatic imports and that is why I'm interested in it.
Module file names also work as implicit names for a default export in this sense.

I'm working in a codebase that includes many snippets like this:

```js
function Factory(...) { ... }

export default Object.assign(Factory, { dependencies });
```

Although the exported value has a `.name` property that correctly describes it as `Factory`, my editors (VSCode, Emacs w/LSP) don't recognize it for automatic imports.

Are there any other ways to implicitly name imports in ES6 and above?

I have tried to get JSDoc annotations to assist but was unable to make it work.
I cannot use this solution:

```js
function FactoryInner(...) { ... }

const Factory = Object.assign(FactoryInner, { dependencies });
export default Factory;
```

@VilgotanL suggested this approach:

```js
function Factory(...) { ... }

Object.assign(Factory, { dependencies });
export default Factory;
```

It is a good suggestion but I would be interested in hearing others if there are other ways of doing this.

Comment: Object.assign sets properties directly on `FactoryInner` and returns it, so what if you just define `Factory` and use `Object.assign` on a line by itself, and then export `Factory`?

Comment: @VilgotanL Good suggestion. I added it to the question for clarification. I am getting a little concerned that it's not a direct enough question but am not sure how to improve it in that regard.

Comment: By converting it to a named export and make it explicit.